# I was snooping around my computer, and found this. Is it normal? (MabookPro, mid 2012, ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: partitioning, mount, macosx

The /dev/sda4 partition has my OSX boot, and I don't wanna lose that. Is it okay if it isn't mounted? And are all these other partitions normal? I only partitioned once when installing Ubuntu.

```
harvey@harvey-MacBookPro:~$ df -H
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda4       255G  6.2G  236G   3% /
    none            4.1k     0  4.1k   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            4.2G  4.1k  4.2G   1% /dev
    tmpfs           828M  1.4M  827M   1% /run
    none            5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
    none            4.2G  193k  4.2G   1% /run/shm
    none            105M   50k  105M   1% /run/user
    /dev/sda1       207M   22M  186M  11% /boot/efi
```

Comment: ? `/dev/sda4` *is* mounted. It's really the only linux partition mounted...

Answer (score 1):

> /dev/sda4 partition has my OSX boot

No, it does not. It is the root system for your Ubuntu. `/dev/sda1` holds you EFI boot; that is the one that lets you boot into operating systems (plural!).

> And are all these other partitions normal?

Yes. Do take notice of the "NONE" in the filesystem column. This indicates a partition that is not physical but stored in memory. See also: [what does device node 'none' means in file system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521102/what-does-device-node-none-means-in-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

/dev/sda4 is mounted at the root of the filesystem, which is what / represents.
It's sort of like the root of the Ubuntu filesystem tree, everything else comes under root, unless you specifically mount parts of your system on other partitions.

When you type a file path, that first / represents root.